# simple priveleges/chmod setup doesn't work

Tags: linux, chmod

here is the directory listing:

```
drwxrwSr--. 31 storage storage 4096 Nov 20 23:12 storage
```

`id` returns `uid=501(peter) gid=501(peter) groups=501(peter),504(office),505(www),506(storage),507(media)`

looks ok? but when I try to enter this this I am getting

`-bash: cd: storage: Permission denied`

What am I doing wrong?

I want to make dir `storage` accesible (read) for everyone, and writes should be allowed only for users from `storage` group. Also I want new files to be created with `storage` group by default

Comment: why downvote???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everybody can read if your directory doesn't have world execute access, so first you need to

```
$ sudo chmod o+x storage
```

Furthermore, I don't know what the capital S mode means, never seen it like that, but I think that is where your problem lies; the setuid bit should be a lower case s. if that is the sticky bit, remove it and set it to normal:

```
$ sudo chmod 0775 storage
```

(Sudo not necessary if you can log in as **storage**).

// EDIT
To have new files default to storage group, you need to add the setuid bit.

```
$ sudo chmod g+s storage
```

Another cause for your problem may be that while `id` gives you the correct output, your shell isn't updated. If you added yourself to the storage group in this session, make sure to log out and log back in again to make your shell aware of the change.

Comment: I didn't know about I need execution access to list dir contents

Comment: Ah! That's one thing to never forget! To execute a directory means to be able to look what's inside!